# Getting XML information

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm having some intense problems.  I've found many questions that are similar and some worked...for a while.  So I decided it was time to ask my own question.

I am uploading an XML file using the FileReader API and then reading it in as a string and then looking for elements and attributes like so:

```js
reader.onload = function (e) {
        var Library = new String(e.target.result);
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(Library, "text/xml");
            $(xmlDoc).find('book').each(function () {

                Pages = [];
                $(this).find("page").each(function () {
                    Page = [];
                    try {
                        Page[0] = this.getAttributeNode("number").nodeValue;
                        Page[1] = this.getAttributeNode("words").nodeValue;
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    Pages.push(Page);
                });
            });
        }
}
```

and I keep on getting either TypeError or this:

```
[09:11:08.523] TypeError: $(...).getAttributeNode is not a function
```

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: Your code also seems to be full of syntax errors; you're missing some closing parenthesis `)`.

Comment: Sorry, there aren't any syntax errors, thats just me typing it into SO
The line its occurring on is the ones with .nodeValue at the end.

Comment: well, the first step would be to fix your typing and make sure you provide in the question the code you actually used.

Comment: I have fixed it, it is the code i have actually used.

Comment: ok, I was asking because the error message makes me think you actually used $(this).getAttributeNode in the code.

Comment: I don't understand why you're mixing jQuery (`$(this).each(...)`) and then low-level DOM (`.getAttributeNode()`). Stick with homogeneous jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/kzcBE/

Comment: Why would anybody downvote this? this is a legit question.
I'm doing it this way b/c I'm still learning JS I guess.
Okay Richard JP Le Guen, your last worked. can you re-write it as an answer so I can accept and up?

Comment: @ShannonStrutz - Done. It's likely it was voted down because you posted a code snippet which was full of syntax errors - your latest version of the code *still* is missing a `);`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that one.  I fixed it! I hope somebody else finds this useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you're mixing jQuery (`$(this).each(...)`) and then low-level DOM (`.getAttributeNode()`). Stick with homogeneous jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/kzcBE

```
var xmlMarkup = "<example>\n" +
                "  <book>\n" +
                "    <page number='p1' words='1104' />\n" +
                "    <page number='p2' words='1230' />\n" +
                "  </book>\n" +
                "  <book>\n" +
                "    <page number='p1' words='123' />\n" +
                "    <page number='p2' words='145' />\n" +
                "  </book>\n" +
                "</example>";

var Library = new String(xmlMarkup);
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(Library, "text/xml");
    $(xmlDoc).find('book').each(function () {
        $(this).find("page").each(function () {
            var numberAttr = $(this).attr("number");
            var wordsAttr = $(this).attr("words");
            console.log("page number: " + numberAttr);
            console.log("word count: " + wordsAttr);
        });
    });
}
```